# How to set Azure RM Vnet Gateway type to basic

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

I recently was billed by Microsoft for $140 for my Azure Vnet VPN gateway. I have checked on the documentation and realized the default gateway created is Standard gateway/SKU which cost $140 instead of basic gateway which cost $38.

Since basic gateway is good enough to serve my use. I would like to change the Azure RM Vnet gateway to basic gateway but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I tried delete and recreate the standard gateway but there is no option for me to choose type of gateways during the create process.

Can anyone give me some clue ?

Thanks,
CK

Comment: Just so everyone knows: This may work in the Legacy mode, but if you try to resize a VpnGw1 to basic is not allowed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via Azure PowerShell CMDLets

1) Download Azure Powershell
https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WindowsAzurePowershellGet.3f.3f.3fnew.appids

2) Run Azure Powershell-ISE (the one opens with a script pane and runs with intellisense)

3) Apply following Powershell cmdlets

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

(Use your Microsoft of Organizational account which has access to run Azure subscription)

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId 'YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'
```

If you don't know your subscriptionId, login to management portal (manage.windowsazure.com)
On the left menu, in Settings, you can view your SubscriptionName and SubscriptionId

```
Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway -Name 'YOUR_VIRTUAL_NETWORK_GATEWAY_NAME' -ResourceGroupName 'RESOURCE_GROUP_OF_THE_GATEWAY' | Resize-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway -GatewaySku 'Basic'
```

Comment: I'm getting the error ```Resize-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGateway : Resizing gateways is not allowed from V1 sizes to V2 sizes OR from Generation1
sizes to Generation2 sizes and vice versa.``` when trying to resize. But my VPN is Generation1 VpnGw1. I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available through the new portal.

Click your Gateway then click on Configuration and there is an SKU dropdown.

[image: See the picture]